# How to extrude faces with a value of its area?

Tags: python, extrude

I'm trying to extrude faces in edit mode , each face is separated , extruding values is taken from face area , but the resulting extruding values seems not correct 
[image]

this is the code 
[image]

```
    import bpy
import bmesh
# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
lm = list (bm.faces) 
l = len(lm)
print(l)
for f in range (0,l) :

    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bm.faces[f].select=True
    ar = bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons[f].area
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_faces_move(MESH_OT_extrude_faces_indiv={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={"value":ar*-5})
```

Comment: Could you please add the *code* to the question? What's your actual goal?

Comment: It looks like "area" is not representative of face size. Have you applied scaling to the Mesh first?

Comment: yes its applied , but it giving right value in the console , big faces gives .05 small faces gives .007 , I tried to divide 1 by the value ,  it gives the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the answer 
the problem was in using extrude individual faces command for this operation , when I change it to ordinary extrude for flat objects and extrude faces along normal for curved objects , that solved the problem 
I added scale in the end to give that shape
you can change the multiplayer with ar variable in the extrude command to control extrusion value

[image]
[image]

this is the code

```
import bpy  #
import bmesh

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)



for f in bm.faces :
    e = f.index

    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bm.faces[e].select=True

    ar = bpy.context.active_object.data.polygons[e].area
    print (ar)
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_shrink_fatten(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"use_normal_flip":False, "mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={"value":-2*ar })

    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.6, 0.6, 0.6) )
```

Comment: Good job, they look awesome

Comment: Thanks man ^=^